# Selenium Python unable to find_element_by_link_text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium in conjunction with BeautifulSoup. To be more specific, I'm trying to click the link `NCAA Division I` from the drop down menu [here](http://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard/_/date/20161122) (initially it says `Top 25`).

The HTML tag for the link looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#" data-type="conference" data-week="null-null-null" data-group="50">NCAA Division I</a></li>
```

To me, it seems straight forward: `driver.find_element_by_link_text('NCAA Division I').click()`

Is this because `href="#"` or maybe because the `<a>` tag is embedded in a `<li>` tag?

Here's what happens:

```
(Pdb) driver.find_element_by_link_text('NCAA Division I').click()
*** NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"NCAA Division I"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64)
```

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime
import os
from selenium import webdriver

scores_link = "http://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard/_/date/20161122"
r = requests.get(scores_link)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(scores_link)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('NCAA Division I').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the "NCAA Division I" will only come after mouse hover, so we have to use ActionChains from selenium(http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

try this code, it will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard/_/date/20161122')

el2=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//header[@class='automated-header']//button[.='Top 25']")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(el2).click().perform()

driver.find_element_by_link_text('NCAA Division I').click()
```